Profile Custom Field Default Value from URL
I have created a profile which includes a contact reference custom field. Is it possible to prefill this field using a query parameter from the URL? My custom field is household_25 (I checked the name in the database) and I have tried using mydomain.com?household_25=[contact id here] but this is not working.
